# Chrome browser push notification with data?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, push-notification, web-push, progressive-web-apps

The chrome browser pops up a balloon with data as shown below

[image]

But Mozilla says the [PushEvent.data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PushEvent/data) is still experimental

> This is an experimental technology
> Because this technology's specification has not stabilized, check the compatibility table for the proper prefixes to use in various browsers. Also note that the syntax and behavior of an experimental technology is subject to change in future versions of browsers as the spec changes.

> Note: This isn't yet supported on any browser.

Now how facebook detect **5 notifications**?, Are they re-establishing a http connection to detect it? or is it really coming with the **PushEvent.data**

Comment: _“Now how facebook detect 5 notifications?”_ – they are not “detecting” anything, they just count the number of notifications the user has on their end (meaning _Facebook_ notifications, which do not have anything to do with the browser notification) – and then they just send the _text_ “You have 5 new notifications” via the Push API.

Answer (score 2):

It is not coming from PushEvent.data, that is not yet fully implemented in Chrome.

The current process is that when the push event is received by your Service Worker you need to make a new `fetch` request from inside your `pushnotification` JS handler to your server.  This means that you have to handle all the logic yourself but you can do a number of things:

1. Maintain some knowledge or state of the user on the server and then push that back to the user and just show the notification directly
2. Maintain some knowledge on the client as well and sync the changes in your SW from your local data store and then update the notification based off that.

Comment: Firefox nightly has a version of this but you'll want to hunt out a module to handle the encryption.